# Method input showing unexpected output

Tags: java

I have a method called processClaims() which takes input from the user "by asking how many files need to be claimed". The method is shown below.

```
public void processClaims() {
        int size = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        String suffix = " ", aClaim = " ";
        System.out.println("How many claims will be filed?");
        size = input.nextInt();

        while (size <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid integer! Re-enter the number of claims to be filed: ");
            size = input.nextInt();
        }

        EarthquakeInsurance[] claims = new EarthquakeInsurance[size];
        for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {
            j = (i + 1) % 10;
            k = (i + 1) % 100;

            suffix = j == 1 && k != 11 ? "st" :
                    j == 2 && k != 12 ? "nd" :
                            j == 3 && k != 13 ? "rd" : "th";
            claims[i] = new EarthquakeInsurance();
            if (i > 0) {
                System.out.println("Is this " + i + suffix + " claim for the same property owner? 'Y' or 'N': ");
                cont = input.next().charAt(0);
                if (cont == 'n' || cont == 'N') {
                    claims[i].setInsured();
                }
                else{
                    claims[i].setInsured(claims[i].getInsured());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                claims[i].setInsured();
                claims[i].setHomeInsVal();
                claims[i].setRichter();
            }
            input.nextLine();
            aClaim = String.format("%n%nPAYOUT FOR EARTHQUAKE DAMAGE"
                            +   "%n%nHomeowner:  %S"
                            +   "%n%nDate:  %tD"
                            +   "%nTime:  %tr%n"
                            +   "%n%-52s %4s $%,20.2f"
                            +   "%nDeductible %47s %,20.2f"
                            +   "%n%46s TOTAL %4s $%,20.2f%n",
                    claims[i].getInsured(), dateTime, dateTime, claims[i].getMessage(), " ",
                    claims[i].getPayout(), " ",
                    claims[i].getDeductible(), " ",
                    " ", claims[i].getPayout() +
                            claims[i].getDeductible());


            aClaim += claimsReport;
            for ( EarthquakeInsurance eachClaim : claims);
            System.out.println(claims);
        }
    }
```

The problem is with the array or the for loop I belive. The output is shown below which isn't correct

```
[LInsuranceSystem$EarthquakeInsurance;@548c4f57
```

If that is wrong here is the whole code, I am having trouble debugging this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Slack
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        InsuranceSystem insuranceSystem = new InsuranceSystem();
        insuranceSystem.start();
    }
}

class InsuranceSystem {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    ArrayList<String> claimsReport = new ArrayList<>();
    EarthquakeInsurance[] claims;
    String fileName = " ";
    char cont = ' ', correct = ' ';

    public InsuranceSystem() {

    }

    public void start() throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("MUTUALLY ACCIDENTAL INC.");
        System.out.println("Do you want an analysis of earthquake coverage for your property? Enter 'Y' or 'N': ");
        cont = input.next().charAt(0); //reads user input from input and applies to it var cont
        input.nextLine(); //clears buffer
        if (cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y') {
            processClaims();
            writeClaimsRecords();
            checkInputFile();
        }
        printThankYou();
    }

    public void processClaims() {
        int size = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        String suffix = " ", aClaim = " ";
        System.out.println("How many claims will be filed?");
        size = input.nextInt();

        while (size <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid integer! Re-enter the number of claims to be filed: ");
            size = input.nextInt();
        }

        EarthquakeInsurance[] claims = new EarthquakeInsurance[size];
        for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {
            j = (i + 1) % 10;
            k = (i + 1) % 100;

            suffix = j == 1 && k != 11 ? "st" :
                    j == 2 && k != 12 ? "nd" :
                            j == 3 && k != 13 ? "rd" : "th";
            claims[i] = new EarthquakeInsurance();
            if (i > 0) {
                System.out.println("Is this " + i + suffix + " claim for the same property owner? 'Y' or 'N': ");
                cont = input.next().charAt(0);
                if (cont == 'n' || cont == 'N') {
                    claims[i].setInsured();
                }
                else{
                    claims[i].setInsured(claims[i].getInsured());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                claims[i].setInsured();
                claims[i].setHomeInsVal();
                claims[i].setRichter();
            }
            input.nextLine();
            aClaim = String.format("%n%nPAYOUT FOR EARTHQUAKE DAMAGE"
                            +   "%n%nHomeowner:  %S"
                            +   "%n%nDate:  %tD"
                            +   "%nTime:  %tr%n"
                            +   "%n%-52s %4s $%,20.2f"
                            +   "%nDeductible %47s %,20.2f"
                            +   "%n%46s TOTAL %4s $%,20.2f%n",
                    claims[i].getInsured(), dateTime, dateTime, claims[i].getMessage(), " ",
                    claims[i].getPayout(), " ",
                    claims[i].getDeductible(), " ",
                    " ", claims[i].getPayout() +
                            claims[i].getDeductible());


            aClaim += claimsReport;
            for ( EarthquakeInsurance eachClaim : claims);
            System.out.println(claims);
        }
    }

    public void writeClaimsRecords() throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        String record = " ";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the file name for the claims' records (WARNING: This will erase a pre-existing file!): ");
        fileName = input.nextLine();
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        for(int i = 0; i < claims.length; i++){
            record = String.format("%s, %f, %f%n", claims[i].insured, claims[i].homeInsVal, claims[i].richter);
        }
        outputFile.printf(record);
        outputFile.close();
        System.out.println("Data written to the" + fileName + " file.");
    }

    public void checkInputFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fileRecord = " ";
        File file = new File("Claims.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            fileRecord = inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(fileRecord);
            System.out.println("");
            inputFile.close();

        }
    }

    public void printThankYou() {
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the Earthquake Coverage Analyzer.");
    }

    class EarthquakeInsurance {
        //STUDENTS INSERT LINE COMMENTS DESCRIPTIVE OF THE PURPOSE OF EACH VARIABLE.
        private String insured;
        private String coverage;
        private String message;
        private double homeInsVal;
        private double richter;
        private double payout;
        private double deductible;
        private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        private boolean repeat;
        private char correct;

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public EarthquakeInsurance() {
        }//END Default Constructor

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public EarthquakeInsurance(String insured, double homeInsVal, double richter) {
            setInsured(insured);
            setHomeInsVal(homeInsVal);
            setRichter(richter);
        }//END EarthquakeInsurance(String, double, double)

        /**
         * STUDENTS CODE copy() AND PROVIDE METHOD BOX COMMENTS.
         */
        public String copy() {
            String insuranceObj = " ";
            return insuranceObj;
        }

        /**
         * STUDENTS CODE equals AND PROVIDE METHOD BOX COMMENTS.
         */
        public boolean equals(String aClaim) {
            boolean isEqual = false;
            if (isEqual = false) {
                isEqual = true;
            }
            return isEqual;
        }


        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public final void setInsured(String insured) {
            this.insured = insured;

        }//END setInsured(String):  final void

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public final void setHomeInsVal(double homeInsVal) {
            this.homeInsVal = homeInsVal;
        }//END setHomeInsVal(double):  final void

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public final void setRichter(double richter) {
            this.richter = richter;
        }//END setRichter(double):  final void

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public void setInsured() {
            String insuredCopy = null, first = null, last = null;
            int indexOfSpace = 0;

            do {
                System.out.printf("%nMUTUALLY ACCIDENTAL, INC."
                        + "%nEarthquake Coverage Analyzer"
                        + "%n%nPlease enter your name:  ");

                insured = input.nextLine();

                insuredCopy = new String(insured).replace(" ", "");

                while (!isAlpha(insuredCopy)) {
                    System.out.printf("%nInvalid name!  Please re-enter:  ");
                    insured = input.nextLine();
                    insuredCopy = new String(insured).replace(" ", "");
                }//while insured's name is NOT alphabetic

                System.out.printf("%nYour Name:  %s"
                                + "%n%nIs this name correct?  \'Y\' or \'N\':  ",
                        insured);
                correct = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

                repeat = correct == 'y' ? false : true;
            } while (repeat);  //do-while insured name is not correct

            indexOfSpace = insured.indexOf(" ");  //Locate where the space is in insured.

            if (indexOfSpace > 0) {
                first = Character.toUpperCase(insured.charAt(0))
                        + insured.substring(1, indexOfSpace).toLowerCase();

                last = Character.toUpperCase(insured.charAt(indexOfSpace + 1))
                        + insured.substring(indexOfSpace + 2, insured.length()).toLowerCase();

                insured = first + " " + last;
            }//if there is more than one name, capitalize the first letter in each
            else {
                insured = Character.toUpperCase(insured.charAt(0))
                        + insured.substring(1, insured.length()).toLowerCase();
            }//else capitalize first letter of a single name


        }//END setInsured():  void

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public void setHomeInsVal() {
            do {
                do {
                    System.out.printf("%nPlease enter the insured value of your home:  ");
                    repeat = !input.hasNextDouble();

                    validateNumber();

                } while (repeat);  //END do-while repeats when homeInsVal is invalid

                homeInsVal = input.nextDouble();

                if (homeInsVal < 0) {
                    System.out.printf("%nThe insured value of your home cannot be less than or equal to 0.%n");
                    repeat = true;

                }//END if homeInsVal less than zero then prompt again
                else {
                    System.out.printf("%nHome\'s Insured Value:  $%,.0f"
                                    + "%n%nIs this insured value correct?  \'Y\' or \'N\':  ",
                            homeInsVal);
                    correct = input.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

                    repeat = correct == 'y' ? false : true;
                }//END else validate the correctness of insured value

            } while (repeat);  //END do-while repeats when homeInsVal is not correct

        }//END setHomeInsVal():  final void

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public void setRichter() {
            do {
                do {
                    System.out.printf("%nRichter Scale     Damage Assessment"
                            + "%n     9.0+         Total destruction."
                            + "%n     8.0          Most structures fell."
                            + "%n     7.0          Many buildings destroyed."
                            + "%n     6.0          Many buildings considerably damaged, some collapsed."
                            + "%n     4.5          Damage to poorly constructed buildings."
                            + "%n     3.5          Felt by many people, no destruction."
                            + "%n     0            Generally not felt by people."
                            + "%n%nPlease enter the Richter scale value for the earthquake:  ");

                    repeat = !input.hasNextDouble();

                    validateNumber();

                } while (repeat);  //END do-while repeats when richter is invalid

                richter = input.nextDouble();

                if (richter < 0) {
                    System.out.printf("%nInvalid!  Richter cannot be negative.  Please re-enter.%n");
                    repeat = true;

                }//END if richter less than zero then prompt again
                else {
                    System.out.printf("%nRichter Scale:  %.2f"
                                    + "%n%nIs this richter value correct?  \'Y\' or \'N\':  ",
                            richter);
                    correct = input.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

                    input.nextLine();

                    repeat = correct == 'y' ? false : true;
                }//END else validate the correctness of richter

            } while (repeat);  //END do-while repeats when homeInsVal is not correct

            testRichter();
        }//END setRichter():  void

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        private void testRichter() {
            if (richter >= 9.0) {
                payout = homeInsVal * .90;
                deductible = homeInsVal * .10;
                message = "Total destruction.";
            }//END if richter >= 9.0 else richter < 9.0
            else if (richter >= 8.0) {
                payout = homeInsVal * .80;
                deductible = homeInsVal * .20;
                message = "Most structures fell.";
            }//END if richter >= 8.0 else richter < 8.0
            else if (richter >= 7.0) {
                payout = homeInsVal * .70;
                deductible = homeInsVal * .30;
                message = "Many buildings destroyed.";
            }//END if richter >= 7.0 else richter < 7.0
            else if (richter >= 6.0) {
                payout = homeInsVal * .60;
                deductible = homeInsVal * .40;
                message = "Many buildings considerably damaged, some collapsed.";
            }//END if richter >= 6.0 else richter < 6.0
            else if (richter >= 4.5) {
                payout = homeInsVal * .50;
                deductible = homeInsVal * .50;
                message = "Damage to poorly constructed buildings.";
            }//END if richter >= 4.5 else richter < 4.5
            else if (richter >= 3.5) {
                payout = 0;
                deductible = 0;
                message = "Felt by many people, no destruction.";
            }//END if richter >= 3.5 else richter < 3.5
            else if (richter >= 0) {
                payout = 0;
                deductible = 0;
                message = "Generally not felt by people.";
            }//END if richter >= 0 else richter < 0

        }//END testRichter():  void

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public String getInsured() {
            return insured;
        }//END getInsured():  int

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public double getHomeInsVal() {
            return homeInsVal;
        }//END getHomeInsVal():  double

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public double getRichter() {
            return richter;
        }//END getRichter():  double

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public double getPayout() {
            return payout;
        }//END getPayout():  double

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public double getDeductible() {
            return deductible;
        }//END getDeductible():  double

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }//END getMessage():  String

        /**
         * STUDENTS ARE TO DESCRIBE WHAT'S GOING ON WITH THE CODE IN METHOD BOXES.
         */
        public void validateNumber() {
            if (repeat) //AS LONG AS THE INPUT IS "NOT" AN INTEGER OR DOUBLE
            {
                input.next(); //CONSUME NON-NUMERIC VALUE.
                System.out.printf("%nWarning:  You entered an invalid integer or "
                        + "floating-point value.%n");  //RE-PROMPT
            }//END if repeat when a number is an invalid type

        }//END validateNumber(boolean):  void

        /**
         * chars() returns the integer values of the characters in word.
         * <p>
         * allMatch determines whether the integer values for each character
         * matches the predicate (criterion) that each character is a letter.
         * <p>
         * The :: is a method reference operator for calling isLetter from
         * the Character class.
         *
         * @param word is the incoming String value to test.
         * @return is true when the word is not empty and is alphabetic
         * or false when it isn't.
         */
        public final boolean isAlpha(String word) {
            /* Test to see if the word is not empty AND if each letter
             * in a word is an alphabetic character.
             */
            return word != null && word.chars().allMatch(Character::isLetter);

        }//END isAlpha(String):  final boolean

    }//END CLASS EarthquakeInsurance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake 1)

```
for ( EarthquakeInsurance eachClaim : claims);
```

remove semi

Mistake 2)

```
System.out.println(claims);
```

Yes you are print the whole list

See also [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)